# Specific vocabulary problem: permit + reflexive pronoun

Tags: vocabulary

*She never has more than one chocolate at once.* (permits)

In the dictionary, there is no entry *permit oneself*, but my book gives the answer: *She never permits herself more than one chocolate at once.*
Which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

From [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/permit):

> ***If you permit yourself something***, you allow yourself to do something that you do not normally do or that you think you probably should not do.
>
> - *Captain Bowen permitted himself one cigar a day*. [V pron-refl n]
> - *Only once in his life had Douglas permitted himself to lose control of his emotions*. [VERB pronoun-reflexive to-infinitive]

- She never permits herself more than one chocolate at once.